# Как запустить entity

Tags: php, symfony2

Какая команда на выполнение, чтобы создалась таблица в базе?

И как описать поле datetime  чтобы добавлялась функция NOW()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы описываете сущность в `.yml` файлах, то вот несколько `bash` комманд:

#### Генерация сущностей (Entity.php)

```
$ ./app/console doctrine:generate:entities NameAppBundle
```

#### Генерация миграции

```
$ ./app/console doctrine:migrations:diff
```

#### Применение миграций

```
$ ./app/console doctrine:migrations:migrate
```

#### Для просмотра всех доступных команд с описанием

```
$ ./app/console
```

А для типа поля `datetime` я использую [prePersist и/или preUpdate](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html)

Comment: накопал пока ждал, вот сейчас ищу как сделать поле которое не должно создаться в базе

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich так пишите в Entity.php свойство, а в yml файл его не указываете, и его не будет в базе

Comment: Просто сделал так  
@var string $file 
    private $file; Ищу теперь как datetime now() поле описать

Comment: options={"default": "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"} так сделал

Answer (score 1):

Хочу обратить внимание при использования NOW() на следующие моменты:

1. При использовании NOW() - приложение зависит от настроек
   даты/времени (а они могут запросто отличаться от настроек
   веб-сервера) сервера СУБД, про это можно легко забыть, ладно если
   это поле используется исключительно для внутренних целей приложения,
   а если это дата, например, бронирования и можно случайно забыть
   преобразовать дату к нужной временной зоне
2. Когда значение по-умолчанию задается в конфиге для сущности, а не в конструкторе, то может случиться такая коллизия, что создан новый экземпляр
   сущности, который еще не сохранен в СУБД, а вы попытаетесь
   обратиться к такому полю, и сделать с ним что-то, и если не
   проверять значение на null (в случае даты), то можно получить
   ошибку, ведь поле еще не проинициализировано. Зачем в голове держать ту информацию?
3. К чему я подвожу, на
   мой взгляд удобное место для задания значения по-умолчанию - это
   конструктор сущности, во-первых, легче понять и помнить какие
   значения по-умолчанию присваиваются полям, во-вторых такие поля уже
   будут проинициализированы при создании экземпляра класса, в третьих
   приложение зависит только от настроек веб-сервера (в части временной
   зоны)
4. А если в приложении требуется особая логика, то как было отмечено выше, все значения можно инициализировать с помощью событий доктрины.

Answer (score 0):

Вот Вам небольшой пример с [оф.документации](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html)

```
use AppBundle\Entity\Product;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

// ...
public function createAction()
{
    $product = new Product();
    $product->setName('A Foo Bar');
    $product->setPrice('19.99');
    $product->setDescription('Lorem ipsum dolor');

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $em->persist($product);
    $em->flush();

    return new Response('Created product id '.$product->getId());
}
```